# Passing JSON object by value or reference

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am usling nlohmann's JSON library to parse a JSON file. In this context I wondered it if is best practice to pass a JSON object by value or reference in terms of efficiency and overhead associated with passing the object.

Here is a short example showing I would pass it by value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"

void read_json(nlohmann::json j) /// pass by value or reference?
{
    ///...
}

int main()
{
    std::string file_name = "asd.json";

    std::ifstream filename_stream(file_name);
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(filename_stream);

    read_json(j);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: always pass by reference

Comment: @randnum-1 that's not always a given fact. Sometimes it's better to pass by value or *const* reference. It's not black and white. The compilers optimizer does really well with copies (usually) but not so much when you add memory references (pointers/references). You *always* need to benchmark.

Comment: In your example, you should pass by (const) reference to avoid copying the whole internals of the JSON value. Of course, you should benchmark, but passing by value has the danger of resulting in expensive copies whereas using references do not.

Comment: @NielsLohmann AFAICS "the whole internals" amounts to only a uint8_t and a (64 bit) json_value, so quite small after all. But you probably knew that.

Comment: I would try not to pass by value. The internals are vectors/maps/strings/int64_t/double/bool depending of your type, and if the value is nested, then it can grow pretty fast. Treat a JSON value like a vector of unknown size.